# What to do with EDMX file in an Entity Framework Re-Usable Library Project

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, visual-studio, shared-libraries

I am still very new to Entity Framework and am trying to create a .dll that can be used for company-wide applications.

The challenge I am facing is that since this is a fairly large company, the database EF is querying from has **hundreds** of tables and, say, 30 or so tables that would be used fairly often.

I'm thinking the correct way to make this dll would be to include, at the very least, the 30 most used tables directly into it, but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to do this and, at the same time, can't think of any better way... Maybe create separate dlls on a per-department / per-need basis and only include the necessary tables **or** is it perfectly fine / won't rob performance if I just include a whole lot of tables into my EF library?

I hope that makes sense and ANY advice / direction will always be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Comment: What makes you think performance will be an issue if you include all of the tables? Are you worried about people in different departments using tables they aren't supposed to be using?

Comment: Truly, @CamBruce, my question was more out of fear that I as doing something wrong by just adding everything... I don't see the other departments seeing the other tables as being an issue, I just wanted to know what the more seasoned pros were doing... Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DLL`, you can add as many `EDMX` files as you need so just add one `per-department` and one for `per-need basis`.

No need create 2 `DLLs`.

Comment: Thanks, @meda, I was hoping it wouldn't be an issue to add them all in, I just wanted to firstly make sure that was what more seasoned pros did!!

Comment: I have done this before, I had an entity for students and another one for professors, it worked out really well, both my project were pointing to the same DLL, just remember to rebuild the whole solution each time you make changes